# JdbcMetadataStore for filtering

Tags: spring-integration

I have flow that I want to implement JdbcMetadataStore in the filers, I used SimpleMetadataStore() but this is causing  issues as it an in memory store, I need to use a shared metadata store, so I have Postgres DB installed and I can see that Jdbc supports it, I declared a bean as per documents to return a JdbcMetadataStore but I'm not sure how I can use this in the filters, tried to search a lot for any example but could not find a one, note that I'm using FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter as well as my datasource for Postgres is all setup in my application properties. I have pasted my code here anyone can please guide me on how to move forward?

```
private DataSource dataSource;

    public IntegrationFlow localToFtpFlow(Branch myBranch){

    return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(myBranch.getBranchCode()))

                .filter(new ChainFileListFilter<File>()
                        .addFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter("final" + myBranch.getBranchCode() +".csv"))
                        .addFilter(new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(), "foo"))),
                        e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(10_000)))
            .transform( p ->{
                LOG1.info("Sending file " + p + " to FTP branch " + myBranch.getBranchCode());

                return p;
            })


            .log()
            .handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter(createNewFtpSessionFactory(myBranch),FileExistsMode.REPLACE)
                    .useTemporaryFileName(true)
                    .autoCreateDirectory(false)
                    .remoteDirectory(myBranch.getFolderPath()))
            .get();
}


public DefaultFtpSessionFactory createNewFtpSessionFactory(Branch branch){
    final DefaultFtpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    factory.setHost(branch.getHost());
    factory.setUsername(branch.getUsern());
    factory.setPort(branch.getFtpPort());
    factory.setPassword(branch.getPassword());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public MetadataStore metadataStore(final DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcMetadataStore(dataSource);
}
```

error arising before I created the table manually, but shouldn't it be created automatically in Postgres as the DB is supported:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO INT_METADATA_STORE(METADATA_KEY, METADATA_VALUE, REGION) SELECT ?, ?, ? FROM INT_METADATA_STORE WHERE METADATA_KEY=? AND REGION=? HAVING COUNT(*)=0]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "int_metadata_store" does not exist
```

Logging info regarding the issue when adding another flow for the second server, it will trigger the first flow handling method and sending the data to ftp server for both:

```
Saved Branch : BEY
Hibernate: select branch0_._id as _id1_0_0_, branch0_.branch_code as branch_c2_0_0_, branch0_.folder_path as folder_p3_0_0_, branch0_.ftp_port as ftp_port4_0_0_, branch0_.host as host5_0_0_, branch0_.password as password6_0_0_, branch0_.usern as usern7_0_0_ from branch branch0_ where branch0_._id=?
BEY
2019-01-07 15:11:25.816  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.intermediateChannel' has 2 subscriber(s).
2019-01-07 15:11:25.817  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started 1.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1
2019-01-07 15:11:25.817  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {transformer} as a subscriber to the '1.channel#0' channel
2019-01-07 15:11:25.817  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.1.channel#0' has 1 subscriber(s).
2019-01-07 15:11:25.817  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started 1.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
2019-01-07 15:11:25.829  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : started stockInboundPoller
BEY
2019-01-07 15:11:25.984  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {message-handler} as a subscriber to the '1o.channel#2' channel
2019-01-07 15:11:25.984  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.1o.channel#2' has 1 subscriber(s).
2019-01-07 15:11:25.984  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started 1o.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1
2019-01-07 15:11:25.984  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {transformer} as a subscriber to the '1o.channel#0' channel
2019-01-07 15:11:25.984  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.1o.channel#0' has 1 subscriber(s).
2019-01-07 15:11:25.984  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started 1o.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
2019-01-07 15:11:25.984  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : started 1o.org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean#0
2019-01-07 15:11:42.655  INFO 12940 --- [ask-scheduler-4] o.s.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession   : File has been successfully transferred from: /ftp/erbranch/EDMS/FEFO/FEFOexportBEY.csv
Hibernate: select branch0_._id as _id1_0_, branch0_.branch_code as branch_c2_0_, branch0_.folder_path as folder_p3_0_, branch0_.ftp_port as ftp_port4_0_, branch0_.host as host5_0_, branch0_.password as password6_0_, branch0_.usern as usern7_0_ from branch branch0_
Hibernate: insert into branch (branch_code, folder_path, ftp_port, host, password, usern) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select currval('branch__id_seq')
Saved Branch : JNB
Hibernate: select branch0_._id as _id1_0_0_, branch0_.branch_code as branch_c2_0_0_, branch0_.folder_path as folder_p3_0_0_, branch0_.ftp_port as ftp_port4_0_0_, branch0_.host as host5_0_0_, branch0_.password as password6_0_0_, branch0_.usern as usern7_0_0_ from branch branch0_ where branch0_._id=?
JNB
2019-01-07 15:13:36.099  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.intermediateChannel' has 3 subscriber(s).
2019-01-07 15:13:36.099  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started 2.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1
2019-01-07 15:13:36.099  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {transformer} as a subscriber to the '2.channel#0' channel
2019-01-07 15:13:36.099  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.2.channel#0' has 1 subscriber(s).
2019-01-07 15:13:36.099  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started 2.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
2019-01-07 15:13:36.099  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : started stockInboundPoller
JNB
2019-01-07 15:13:36.130  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {message-handler} as a subscriber to the '2o.channel#2' channel
2019-01-07 15:13:36.135  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.2o.channel#2' has 1 subscriber(s).
2019-01-07 15:13:36.135  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started 2o.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1
2019-01-07 15:13:36.135  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {transformer} as a subscriber to the '2o.channel#0' channel
2019-01-07 15:13:36.135  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.2o.channel#0' has 1 subscriber(s).
2019-01-07 15:13:36.135  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started 2o.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
2019-01-07 15:13:36.135  INFO 12940 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : started 2o.org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean#0
2019-01-07 15:13:40.981  INFO 12940 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession   : File has been successfully transferred from: /ftp/erbranch/EDMS/FEFO/FEFOexportJNB.csv
2019-01-07 15:13:46.085  INFO 12940 --- [ask-scheduler-7] o.s.i.file.FileReadingMessageSource      : Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=BEY\finalBEY.csv, headers={file_originalFile=BEY\finalBEY.csv, id=42a97889-7bfb-8f77-75d8-4e7988a368f9, file_name=finalBEY.csv, file_relativePath=finalBEY.csv, timestamp=1546866826085}]]
2019-01-07 15:13:46.086  INFO 12940 --- [ask-scheduler-7] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=BEY\finalBEY.csv, headers={file_originalFile=BEY\finalBEY.csv, id=108a92b0-db42-620e-1c46-90652a071220, file_name=finalBEY.csv, file_relativePath=finalBEY.csv, timestamp=1546866826086}]
2019-01-07 15:13:46.160  INFO 12940 --- [ask-scheduler-8] o.s.i.file.FileReadingMessageSource      : Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=JNB\finalJNB.csv, headers={file_originalFile=JNB\finalJNB.csv, id=d3b2c6a0-2e9c-42a8-c224-0ed9cbbfaabb, file_name=finalJNB.csv, file_relativePath=finalJNB.csv, timestamp=1546866826160}]]
2019-01-07 15:13:46.161  INFO 12940 --- [ask-scheduler-8] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=JNB\finalJNB.csv, headers={file_originalFile=JNB\finalJNB.csv, id=e34070c2-e6ff-e5e1-8c64-4af697ab1032, file_name=finalJNB.csv, file_relativePath=finalJNB.csv, timestamp=1546866826161}]
2019-01-07 15:13:47.129  INFO 12940 --- [ask-scheduler-7] o.s.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession   : File has been successfully transferred to: /ftp/erbranch/EDMS/FEFO/finalBEY.csv.writing
2019-01-07 15:13:47.534  INFO 12940 --- [ask-scheduler-7] o.s.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession   : File has been successfully renamed from: /ftp/erbranch/EDMS/FEFO/finalBEY.csv.writing to /ftp/erbranch/EDMS/FEFO/finalBEY.csv
2019-01-07 15:13:49.772  INFO 12940 --- [ask-scheduler-8] o.s.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession   : File has been successfully transferred to: /ftp/erbranch/EDMS/FEFO/finalJNB.csv.writing
2019-01-07 15:13:50.757  INFO 12940 --- [ask-scheduler-8] o.s.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession   : File has been successfully renamed from: /ftp/erbranch/EDMS/FEFO/finalJNB.csv.writing to /ftp/erbranch/EDMS/FEFO/finalJNB.csv
```

You can find my app here
https://github.com/EliasKhattar/Spring-Integration-Project/tree/master/spring4ftpappftp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `metadataSource(dataSource)` instead of `new SimpleMetadataStore()` in the filter constructor.

**EDIT**

I just copied your flow into a new app (made a few changes, but not to the filter) and everything works fine for me...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So54039852Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So54039852Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow localToFtpFlow(DataSource dataSource) {

        return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File("/tmp/foo"))

                .filter(new ChainFileListFilter<File>()
                        .addFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter(".*\\.csv"))
                        .addFilter(new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore(dataSource), "foo"))),
                    e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(10_000)))
                .log()
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentMetadataStore metadataStore(final DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcMetadataStore(dataSource);
    }

}
```

and

```
$ touch /tmp/foo/foo.csv
...
$ touch /tmp/foo/bar.csv
```

and

```
2019-01-09 12:46:26.332  INFO 43329 --- [ask-scheduler-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=/tmp/foo/foo.csv, headers={file_originalFile=/tmp/foo/foo.csv, id=e0613529-a657-fbd3-5e67-8bb53a58b5ca, file_name=foo.csv, file_relativePath=foo.csv, timestamp=1547055986330}]
2019-01-09 12:47:26.487  INFO 43329 --- [ask-scheduler-5] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=/tmp/foo/bar.csv, headers={file_originalFile=/tmp/foo/bar.csv, id=4feb74b6-d711-f028-70c7-83cdfcd0aeec, file_name=bar.csv, file_relativePath=bar.csv, timestamp=1547056046487}]
```

and

```
mysql> select * from INT_METADATA_STORE;
+---------------------+----------------+---------+
| METADATA_KEY        | METADATA_VALUE | REGION  |
+---------------------+----------------+---------+
| foo/tmp/foo/bar.csv | 1547056039000  | DEFAULT |
| foo/tmp/foo/foo.csv | 1547055980000  | DEFAULT |
+---------------------+----------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I don't see the file again even after a restart, but if I change the date on one of the files...

```
$ touch /tmp/foo/bar.csv
```

and

```
2019-01-09 12:51:58.534  INFO 44430 --- [ask-scheduler-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=/tmp/foo/bar.csv, headers={file_originalFile=/tmp/foo/bar.csv, id=f92d6b36-c948-37cc-ca56-9ef28de336f2, file_name=bar.csv, file_relativePath=bar.csv, timestamp=1547056318532}]
```

Comment: After I added metadataStore(dataSource) in the filter I had to change the metadataStore to ConcurrentMetadataStore as this filter does not take MetaDataStore type, then I had to declare a Datasource variable to be used in the method in the filter, after testing the code I'm facing an error which I'm including above in the code, seems that it is not creating the table in the postgres although the jdbc connections are all showing correct as per debugging@Gary Russell

Comment: I created a table in postgres with the name in small char as the DB does not read capital letters, after that it worked to parse the info in the table, but the same issue is still there, if I have two files that are already processed and I drop one file in one server then it sends both again at the same time not only the new one, Am I missing anything in the filters? Also if I create the initial flow which suppose to pick the file,creates new and sends it, it is only pulling the file from FTP and I have to add another ftp flow so that it sends back the new files@Gary russell

Comment: The filter should be an `FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`; there is also a localFilter, which needs the `FileSystemPersistentFileListFilter`.

Comment: Do you mean that I should replace FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter with FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter? tried so but it is giving filter type issue maybe cause I'm using ChainFileListFilter? should that be replaced?also about the localFilter where do you mean that should be entered?thank you@Gary Russell

Comment: The inbound channel adapter has 2 filters (`.filter()`) and `localFilter()`). The first one determines which files are fetched from FTP and copied to the local file system; the second determines which files on the file system are sent as messages. If you can upload a simplified project to GitHub, one of us can take a look.

Comment: Method above I'm sending from local to FTP, I'm using Files.inboundAdapter rather Ftp.inboundAdapter, I think this is why I'm not able to use the FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter, basically I have one method that is creating a flow pulling csv from FTP to local folder then handling a method to create a new report after that the above method should send those different new files to FTP(s), the project I uploaded to github just needs couple of ftp servers to poll and a local DB (I'm using Postgres), couldnt simplify the code more :S sorry, I'm ok for a skype call if possible@Gary Russell

Comment: The whole flow config is in folder fefo.springframeworkftp.spring4ftpapp.configuration FTIntegration and if you run the app and go to localhost:8081 you will have on the tool bar option to create an ftp branch and this is managed in the package fefo.springframeworkftp.spring4ftpapp.controllers Branch controller class, my skype name is eliekhattar if it is ok from your end...thanks anyway@Gary Russell

Comment: Sorry; I somehow read `Ftp.inbound...` instead of `Files.inbound...`. Sorry for the confusion; I'll try to take a look later today; I am not able to provide 1:1 support over Skype; sorry.

Comment: Not a problem, your support has always been valuable in spring integration over stackoverflow so we can continue here:)...will be waiting a feedback once you have time to check it...thank you continues help@Gary Russell

Comment: Sorry - didn't get a chance to look at it today; will try again tomorrow (US-EST).

Comment: Your code works fine for me; see the edit to my answer.

Comment: You are definitely right, it is working as designed, I think I found the issue, in the code there is a handle function that takes a method which converts the incoming file to a new file and then this new file is being sent down stream, I can see that this handle method is keeping on writing the new file thus changing the dates every time it writes it and thus the new file is being sent again, I will raise a new question regarding this matter, maybe a way to archive the initial csv file after writing a new one from it and remove it from the folder, thanks again @Gary Russell